# Selecting an item from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to verify if a computer is on a specific vlan at work.  Below is the code I got, but when running through the list I not only get the Yes for stating the computer is on the vlan but You must connect to the vpn as well for the other items.  Is there a way to have it setup where once the first condition is met to skip the second or to evaluate the first condition and if that is not met move on to the second.  Im using python 3.6.2 on windows 7.

```
import socket

IP1 = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

IpAddress = IP1.split('.')

Work = ['30', '40', '50', '70', '221'];

print (Work)

for ip in Work:
    if IpAddress[2] == ip:
        print ('yes')
        break
    elif IpAddress[2] != ip:
        print ('You must connect to the vpn!!')


print (IP1)
```

Comment: De-indent your `elif` so it is not inside your loop.

Comment: You should print out the two things you are comparing (`ip` and `IpAddress[2]`) at the start of the for loop and see what they look like. Also, if you're just making a comparison between `==` and `!=`, you might as well just use an `else` where you are using an `elif`

Comment: When De-indenting it comes up with a syntax error.  The end goal is to have a screen pop up at the user when there not on the work network to connect to the vpn.  The way I got it set up above it prints you must connect to the vpn 5 times.  This is with the else statement in there as well.  I would rather just have one message stating you need to connect to the vpn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your "`else`" (`elif` in this case) is part of the conditional statement within the `for` loop, so it will be evaluated for each iteration.

Python has an `for`-`else` construct as well which is entered after the loop iteration is "exhausted" (`StopIteration`). Here's the documenation ([Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Try the following code for your loop:

```
for ip in Work:
    if IpAddress[2] == ip:
        print ('yes')
        break
else:
    print ('You must connect to the vpn!!')
```

Comment: That fixed it thanks tdube.  Im very new to this so ya.  Also do you guys know of any place with good documentation on how to produce a splash screen with python?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the loop at all to compare the IP to those in the list. Just use `in`:

```
if IpAddress[2] in Work:
    print ('yes')
else:
    print ('You must connect to the vpn!!')
```

Some other variants, in case you do not just want to compare with `==` but something more complex, like seeing whether it matches some subnet mask

```
# also works with more compelx comparisons
if any(IpAddress[2] == ip for ip in Work):
    print ('yes')
else:
    print ('You must connect to the vpn!!')

# if you also want to have the matching element
ip = next((ip for ip in Work if IpAddress[2] == ip), None)
if ip is not None:
    print ('yes, the ip is', ip)
else:
    print ('You must connect to the vpn!!'
```